# How to connect Asana from PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, asana

I am using PHPStorm 8.0.2

Adding server:

Tools > Task & Context > Configure server.

Based on https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/authentication#sts=API%20Keys .

Always getting 403, does anyone tried to connect this from PHPStorm?

Comment: Please check comments at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19852

Comment: I want to add that project id is last part of url of asana project page. Rest of details in link provided by @LazyOne

Comment: Is this a 404 when you try to test it? Or when you try to connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit 15.06.2017:**
The Url's have changed, so if you get a "Bad Request" with seamingly correct settings, check the Task-list urls from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552551/4778443)

Here´s what worked for me based on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19852 from LazyOne´s comment

1) get a <strike>API key</strike> [Personal Access Token](https://app.asana.com/-/account_api) and use that as your Username in the Servers configuration in PHPStorm

2) [Project ID](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19852#viewimage=Asana-project_id.png%3Ffile%3D74-132986%26v%3D0%26c%3Dtrue%26rw%3D808%26rh%3D120%26u%3D1401303792092) comes from the URL if your within the Project (the first long number)

3) Password is your Account Password

**Edit 15.07.2016:**
Asana [deprecates the API keys](https://asana.com/guide/help/api/api#gl-api-key) in favor of the personal Access tokens. But with that it works the same way.

Comment: Seems not working yet. API key functionality seems is deprecated

Comment: @ПавелИванов Works for me, updated it since API-keys are now deprecated, but it basically works the same way

Answer (score 12):

If you need to connect to the project in asana, in the beginning do as described above

1) [Personal Access Token](https://app.asana.com/-/account_api) and use that as your Username in the Servers
configuration in PHPStorm
2) [Project ID](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19852#viewimage=Asana-project_id.png%3Ffile=74-132986&v=0&c=true&rw=808&rh=120&u=1401303792092) comes from the URL if your within the Project (the first
long number)

3.a) In phpStorm change "Task List URL"

with `"{serverUrl}/projects/{project_ID}/tasks?assignee=me"`

to `{serverUrl}/projects/{project_ID}/tasks`

If you want to work with "Personal Tasks"

3.b) In phpStorm change "Task List URL"

`{serverUrl}tasks?workspace=[workspace_id]&assignee=me`

`[workspace_id]` get here `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me`

Comment: I get the error message "JsonPath expression 'id' doesn't match" using these settings.

Comment: @piersb Looks like they changed their json.  Try gid and data.gid under Servers > Server Configuration > path.  You can type right in there.

Answer (score 8):

**Nov 2016** important addition to (mostly) working recipe of @Jonas Krispin:

- password field should be empty, otherwise you  are not going to connect

so, finally:

- Server URL: leave as is (https://app.asana.com/api/1.0)
- Username: Personal Access Token which you generate in your Asana account settings
- Password: empty
- Project ID: number in your project's URL just before "/list" part (`httpx://app.asana.com/0/`**`123456789101112`**`/list`

in PhpStorm 2016.2 settings look as follows:

[image]

*not enough reputation to add a comment*

Comment: For my organization I had to supply my account password. Trying without the password resulted in `Request failed with HTTP error: Bad Request`

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting an error `Request failed with HTTP error: Bad Request` if in the **Task List URL** in the **Server Configuration** tab is set to:

`{serverUrl}/projects/{project_ID}/tasks?assignee=me`

The following setting in that field worked for me (`workspaces={workspaces_ID}`):

`{serverUrl}/projects/{project_ID}/tasks?workspaces={workspaces_ID}`

There is no field for `workspaces_ID`, so it's entered in the field, like:

`{serverUrl}/projects/{project_ID}/tasks?workspaces=336484028`

*PS. Not enough reputation to add a comment*

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Without this change it was not possible to _connect to asana from PHPStorm_ (question)  for me (which is possibly a case for others).

Answer (score 2):

Update 2020 - after last Asana changes task id parametrer must be changed from "id" to "gid" [image: Server Configuration]

Comment: I'm getting Request failed with HTTP error: Not Found with this configuration. :(